# Why https works only on main page? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, http, ssl, https

I can enter to my site by typing, for example: http://home.com or  and it works good, but if I go to https://home.com/example , syles and links (no imgs) refers to http, also the ssl certificate doesn't aprove.
P.S. I use header.php tamplate for home and other pages
p.s.s. Also i change addresses in admin-panel and DB
Sorry for my English!

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Does it give an error, does the page not load? More details will allow us to better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is put the site behind Cloudflare and make a [page rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-) to always use HTTPS by default, that should take care of it by enforcing SSL.
[image]

Comment: omg, thx you, I tried fix this problem so hard, but no results, you solution the best and very easy

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use Cloudflare you can use the plugin: [WP Force SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/), so that you redirect all the files (CSS, JS, etc) to https.